# How to resize a button depending on its text

Tags: c#, winforms, button, text, resize

In the process of translating an application with C# + Winforms, I need to change a button's text depending on the language.

My problem is the following :

Let's say I want to translate a button from "Hi all!" to "Bonjour tout le monde" !

As you can guess, the button's size won't be the same if I enter english text or french one... My question is "simple", how can I manage to resize the button on the fly so the text fits its content in the button ?

So far I got something like that !

[Hi all!]

[Bonjour]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your best bet is to set the [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize) property as described [ach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965886/119477)

However if AutoSize isn't working for you, resizing the button in code is easy enough. You can just need to set the button's width. The trick is making it big enough to fit your text.

```
   using(Graphics cg =  this.CreateGraphics())
   {
       SizeF size = cg.MeasureString("Please excuse my dear aunt sally",this.button1.Font);

       // size.Width+= 3; //add some padding .net v1.1 and 1.0 only
       this.button1.Padding = 3;
       this.button1.Width = (int)size.Width;

       this.button1.Text = "Please excuse my dear aunt sally";
   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to add the padding? `this.button1.Width = (int)size.Width + button1.Padding.Left + button1.Padding.Right;`. And if you have an image to the right or left of the text, then you would have to add the image width.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Based on the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3965742/revisions) I thought so as well and then changed my answer. Since there's a superior answer (Andrew's) and it would be easy for anyone using this answer to determine if you need to account for padding in the size or not I'm going to decline to modify this answer.

Answer (score 31):

There's absolutely no need to use the underlying `Graphics` object as the other posters have said.

If you set the button's `AutoSize` property to true, the `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`, and the `AutoEllipsis` to false, it will resize automatically to fit the text.

That being said, you may need to make several layout adjustments to make this change fit into your UI. You can adjust the button's padding to add space around the text, and you may want to place your buttons in a `TableLayoutPanel` (or something) to stop them from overlapping when they resize.

Edit:
@mastro pointed out that: `AutoEllipsis` is only valid when `AutoSize` is `false` (As explained in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.autoellipsis%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so it can be safely ignored as long as the other three properties are set correctly.

Comment: For the OP's need, this may be a much better solution because it sounds like they are dealing with a fairly straightforward secnario. However the statement "absolutely no need" is misleading. MeasureString is one of the best tools a programmer building custom forms and controls has available. It's also handy for web programmers (via an HTTP handler) to create precisely sized images based on variable text.

Comment: @Tim - I'm not saying anything negative about MeasureString, it has it's uses, but this is unequivocally not one of them. Riddling your code with unnecessary and arbitrary (width += 3) code is a bad practice.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
Button.AutoSize = true;
Button.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
Button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
Button.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable a Button in WinForms grow and/or shrink depending on the size of the Text, you need to set the button's `AutoSize` property to `True` and the `AutoSizeMode` property to `GrowAndShrink`.

```
// C#
btn.AutoSize = true;
btn.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

' VB.NET
btn.AutoSize = True
btn.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
```

Please note that the `AutoSize` property will only allow the button's size to grow if the `AutoSizeMode` property is set to `GrowOnly`; by changing the `AutoSizeMode` property to `GrowAndShrink`, the button will now automatically extend or reduce in width and height based on its `Text` property.

Also note that in setting the two properties as shown above, you can make use of new lines (`Environment.NewLine` or `vbCrLf`) in the Text property and the button will scale down as needed.

Answer (score 1):

As [Andrew Hanlon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965886/880990) explains, you can set `AutoSize = true`.

When doing so, you can also attain a perfect layout of the buttons automatically by placing them on a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

The horizontal distance between them will always stay the same when the `FlowDirection` of the `FlowLayoutPanel` is `LeftToRight` or `RightToLeft`. You can adjust this distance by setting the `Margin` property of the buttons appropriately. You can create groups of buttons by increasing the left margin of buttons beginning a new group.

If you set the `Dock` property of the buttons to `DockStyle.Fill`, they will even grow their width automatically in order to fit to the widest button if the `FlowDirection` of the `FlowLayoutPanel` is `TopDown` or `BottomUp`.

```
btn.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
btn.AutoSize = true;
btn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the `AutoSize` to `true` and the `AutoSizeMode`to `GrowAndShrink`, as suggested in the other answers, you may also need to set the `TextImageRelation` property, if you have set the button image, so that the text doesn't overlap the image.